# Non-invocable memeber 'Text.text' can not be used as a method

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

Trying to change text in a text box, and have multiple lines on it, i found something online talking about "\n" but this came up.

> Non-invocable memeber 'Text.text' can not be used as a method.

This is my code

```
private void Start()
{
    if (creditEnding)
    {
        startText.text("You, died? \n well you should get some sleep anyways");
    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors like this are not unique to game development. This is telling you that the syntax `foo.Bar(argument)` is only valid when `Bar()` is a method you want to call/invoke. `text` is not a method, it's a property. If you want to assign a string to it, you use the assignment operator: `startText.text = "some string";` (or you can call a `SetText()` method if the text type you're using has one: `startText.SetText("some string");`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since text is of type string and not a method, all you need to do is

```
startText.text = "You, died? \n well you should get some sleep anyways";
```